# How Record and Save audio on a browser and save it on a server using flash player

Tags: browser, audio, save, record

I want to record audio and save it on a server. I am creating a task manager and I want to record audio instructions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a start: https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/